# Is it conventional to host your dapp on a subdomain (e.g. app.uniswap.org), and why?

Tags: dapps, dapp-development, react, dapp-design, frontend

I've noticed the design pattern of having an enter app button from the home/landing page which opens the dapp in a new tab is quite common. This is something that I don't see in Web2 design. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: No, there isn't any reason to do so. There are several projects that use their root domain: curve, yearn, zapper.